# Overwrite a value in the .Xlsx if a pariculat string is found using Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have an excel sheet and I can get the necessary block of cell using the below piece of code.

```
   import pandas as pd

    ENVIRONMENT="SIMM"
    excel_file_name=r'C:\Users\spadravsasthu\Desktop\SVN\HSRI-DEV\TEST\checklist.xlsx'
    workbook_sheet = pd.read_excel(excel_file_name,sheet_name='Sheet1',keep_default_na=False)
    df=pd.DataFrame(workbook_sheet,columns=['Environment', 'Available chunk start value','Available chunk end value'])
df['Available chunk start value'] = np.where((df.Environment == 'SIMM'),
                                             df['Available chunk start value'].str.replace('776021800','123456789'),
                                             df['Available chunk start value'])
```

Below is the output of `df`

```
    Environment Available chunk start value Available chunk end value
   7         SIMM                         NaN                 799900000
```

The original values was

```
 Environment Available chunk start value Available chunk end value
       7         SIMM        776021800                  799900000
```

From the above, I want to change `776021800` to `123456789` in the dataframe, but it making it as NaN. Any idea on how can that be done using Pandas!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you simply want to overwrite the excel file after making changes in python? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` to conditionally replace right in the original dataframe, then save that to Excel.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Environment': ['SIMM', 'notSIMM', 'SIMM'],
    'start_value': ['793951420', '793951420', 'something else']
})

print(df)

  Environment     start_value
0        SIMM       793951420
1     notSIMM       793951420
2        SIMM  something else

ENVIRONMENT = 'SIMM'
df['start_value'] = np.where(df.Environment.str.match(ENVIRONMENT), 
                             df['start_value'].str.replace('793951420','793956789'),
                             df['start_value'])
print(df)

  Environment     start_value
0        SIMM       793956789  <-- only this changed
1     notSIMM       793951420
2        SIMM  something else
```

Edit: For your specific case (note, this saves output to new sheet `Sheet2`:

```
import pandas as pd

ENVIRONMENT="SIMM"
excel_file_name=r'C:\Users\spadravsasthu\Desktop\SVN\HSRI-DEV\TEST\checklist.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_name,sheet_name='Sheet1',keep_default_na=False)
df = df[['Environment', 'Available chunk start value','Available chunk end value']]
df['Available chunk start value'] = np.where(df.Environment.str.match(ENVIRONMENT),
                                             df['Available chunk start value'].str.replace('793951420','793956789'),
                                             df['Available chunk start value'])

with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_name, mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

Comment: I tried the above and it has changed the value to NaN for both SIMM and SIMMT. PFb the output of `print(df)`
`7         SIMM                         NaN                 799900000
8        SIMMT                         NaN                 801000000`

Comment: This looks good, Need a very small tuning, This updates whatever matches `SIMM` to `NaN` Not a number, which is not expected If there is some other row with `SIMMT` or `SIMMTT` . The updated answer updates it to NaN for all the strings with pattern `SIMM`. Is there a way to match the exact word under `Environment` column.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what you mean. If you want the Environment value to be _exactly_ SIMM, you can replace `df.Environment.str.match(ENVIRONMENT)` with `df.Environment == ENVIRONMENT`

Comment: The following `df['Available chunk start value'] = np.where((df.Environment == ENVIRONMENT),
                                             df['Available chunk start value'].str.replace('776021800','123456789'),
                                             df['Available chunk start value'])` This matches the exact string, This works. But one last problem is it makes the Replaced value as `NaN`.
`7         SITM                         NaN                 799900000` where as NaN should be `'123456789'`

Comment: Only thing is it not replacing the value with what we want, It is just making them `NaN`, Anyway to correct this!

Comment: I have edited my original question. Please check once